# Translation of 这里开了家医院

Tags: translation, grammar

I found a translation of 这里开了家医院 to "There is a hospital here" but this translation seems to ignore the word 开了。

Does the word 开了 add addition meaning to the sentence which the translation does not include or is it a perfectly valid translation?

Comment: cf.＂汉语水平考试词典开＂，开：［义６］兴办；创立（set up；run）：～创｜他在路边～了一家小吃店｜几个人合伙～了一家贸易公司, there is a hospital = it has been set up, is being run

Comment: check your university or public library for "Introduction to Chinese-English Translation Key Concepts and Techniques"

Comment: cf。 http://www.99lib.net/book/5929/206788.htm D.Hammett, The Dain Curse: I learned where these joints were and then went downtown again,...我问清楚了这两家店开在什么地方，就又回城里去了...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

这里 开了 家 医院。
Here opened a hospital.

They opened up a hospital here.

Translating is also a task of creation. Translators can change a bit the original meaning so the sentence sounds better in the target language.

Comment: They opened up a hospital here.

Answer (score 1):

"There's a hospital here." is okay but it does omit "开了".

In my perspective, "There's a hospital here" = "这里有家医院".

"开了" adds a subtle change to the sentence that, imagine you're no stranger to this place, then someday you find that there's a hospital which you've never known before, then you may say "这里开了家医院".

In translation, you don't necessarily need translate "开了" literally as "someone opened/founded". I suggest to translate this as "这里开了家新医院".

Though there's no "新" in the original sentence, but this could imply the change from "这里没有医院" to "这里有家医院".

Answer (score 0):

Word-to-word translation is not always good.

For example, a similar mistake Chinese English beginners always make:

桌子上有一本书   <-->  There *have* a book on the table

Here, 有 is not always the English word "have".

Answer (score -1):

I think it just means "has just been opened". It is much like the use of the  English perfect tense to give news.